# ruby parsing datetime %Y%m%d%H%M%S

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I have a string like this: `"20130429130501"` (It is date and time with chomped UTC zone info (`.0Z`); it can be represented like `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`). I was trying `DateTime.parse` and `DateTime.strptime` without success. Is it possible to convert it to `DateTime` class object?

Comment: What error are you getting? `DateTime.parse('20130429130501', '%Y%m%d%H%M%S')` seems to be working for me.

Comment: It was my stupid mistake with variable without quotes as argument in parse function. I got my goal. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
require "date"
DateTime.parse("20130429130501", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
# => #<DateTime: 2013-04-29T13:05:01+00:00 ((2456412j,47101s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: /home/muzhagitov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1576:in `new_by_frags': invalid date (ArgumentError)
        from /home/muzhagitov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1621:in `parse'
        from ./Desktop/Ruby/ldap/ldap-script.rb:20